# How convert a List<string> to one long string?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this code in the constructor:

```
readableRss = RssReader.covertRss("http://rotter.net/rss/rotternews.xml");


for (int i = 0; i < newText.Count; i++)
{
    this.scrollLabel1.Text = newText[i];
}
```

When im using a breakpoint on the variable readableRss which is a string i click on the magnifier glass and what i see the format of the readableRss is like this:

First two lines:

```
היום לפני 22 שנה צהל וחיה״א הישראלי בביצוע החיסול הממוקד הראשון מהאוויר -מרתק
Sun, 16 Feb 2014 18:03:30 +0200
```

Then a space empty line then the new two lines and so on like this:

```
מסתמן: המהירות המותרת בכבישי ישראל תועלה ל-120 קמ''ש
Sun, 16 Feb 2014 17:59:21 +0200

סירטון מכונית התופת שנלכדה ופורקה בלבנון נעצרו 3 נשים בפרשה
Sun, 16 Feb 2014 17:55:52 +0200

חשיפה: רשימת ''המבוקשים'' היהודים בפרשיות תג מחיר
Sun, 16 Feb 2014 17:42:35 +0200

ראשון של כדורגל, כדורסל - 16-2-2014 - אשכול מרוכז
Sun, 16 Feb 2014 17:29:21 +0200
```

Now what i did before was assigning this string variable into a label control:

```
this.scrollLabel1.Text = readableRss
```

But now instead a one string bariable i have a List
The List i called it newText look like the string variable visualy:
In index 0 and index 1 two lines then index 2 empty then another two indexs then empty index.

So i did in the constructor:

```
for (int i = 0; i < newText.Count; i++)
            {
                this.scrollLabel1.Text = newText[i];
            }
```

But now the scrollLabel control its content dosent look the same when i was assign to it only the string readableRss.

So what i want to do is to make all the content in the List newText one long string like readableRss and then assign it to the label control.

How can i convert/make the newText List to one long string so it will be the same format like readableRss ?

Comment: I tried now this: string combindedString = string.Join("", newText); but the result when i use a breakpoint and click on the glass i see that its one long text and its not formatted in lines like the variable readableRss.

Comment: Basically, you want a string containning all lines separated by the "\n" char?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want lines, you have to put a line seperator in the join:

```
string combindedString = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, newText);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to use LINQ, you could use something like:

```
string combinedString = testList.Aggregate((a, b) => a + Environment.NewLine + b);
```